# How to proof that Durbin Watson statistics numerator is the covariance?

Tags: durbin-watson-test

I read that: 
1) The null hypothesis used is d=2, if et and et-1 are uncorrelated, et minus et-1 should have twice the variance of et itself. 
2) the numerator of the statistics is covariance

Are we able to proof that the numerator is the covariance? I got the below but not sure if my steps are right. Seems to be far from a covariance formula. 
(et - et-1)^2 
= et^2 -2etet-1 + (et-1)^2
= et^2 -etet-1 + (et-1)^2 -etet-1
If et and et-1 are uncorrelated, then covariance should be 0. Which makes the test statistic 0 and not 2.

Anyone able to enlighten me on this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the numerator technically does not equal the covariance (either as written in most standard formulations for the Durbin-Watson statistic $d$, or even in its adjusted form—when divided by the same size or df).  The two hints I can offer are (1) divide both the numerator and denominator by the sample size, and (2) use the fact that $E[e_t] = E[e_{t-1}] = 0$.  Lastly, if you want to make the calculation easier, let $e_{-1}=e_T$, where there are $T$ total residuals...then you can use the same indexing on the summation in the numerator as in the denominator.

Hope this helps you in your exploration.